# how to join the threads with the main function

Tags: c++, pthreads

hey i am able to create threads but its not joining with the main...the program is not executing the third for loop..ie. the thread joining part...any help would be appreciated

here is my code:

```
for(i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
    pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, thread_sort, (void *) &data[i]);  
}
for(i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
    if( pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL,thread_sort, (void *) &data[i])<0) {
        cout<<"\n Error in creation of threads.....!!!!!!!!";
    } 
    else {
        cout<<"Thread "<<i<<"is Created"<<endl;
    }     
}

for(i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
    pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
    if (pthread_join(thread[i],NULL)<0) {
        cout<<"\n Error in joining Threads";
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
    pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
    if (pthread_join(thread[i],NULL)<0) {
        cout<<"\n Error in joining Threads";
    }                
}
```

You are attempting to join the thread twice here, you should take out the first pthread_join, IE:

```
for(i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
    if (pthread_join(thread[i],NULL)<0) {
        cout<<"\n Error in joining Threads";
    }                
}
```

Also, are error values negative?  The documentation I am finding says "non-zero," so I'm wondering if that should be `pthread_join(thread[i],NULL)!=0` instead.

EDIT:  Try taking out your first loop as well, it ends up calling `pthread_create` twice on the same objects.

Comment: OK, is it not getting to the third loop at all?

Comment: yea its not executing the third loop at all because i tried printing some variable inside loop..its not printing..which means its not going into third for loop..right?

Comment: @user3281808 Which particular problem?? Edit your question please, that was the reason for my down and close vote!

Comment: Probably because it looks like you are doing the same thing above (Calling pthread_create() twice).  Try taking out the first loop.

Comment: @Namfuak ok now iam calling pthread_create() once but the problem still remains the same

Comment: OK, does the program quit with no error?  Throw a segfault?

Comment: @Namfuak The program does not  throw any errors but it hangs after creating the threads

Comment: Does it get out of the second loop but not go into the third?

Comment: @Namfuak Yes it comes out of the second loop but does not go into the third loop.